# Remote Control Plane Transmitter Question

Tags: antenna, transmitter, remote-control

More so of a rc plane hobbyist, so never messed with the workings of the receivers or controllers. I am looking to help with the situation in Ukraine.  Building long range search rc planes as most of the electric drones they use are limited in both range and number. Where cheap rc planes could be used a lot more.
I'm looking for a way to extend the control range to 10-15 miles(i know the FCC rules but this would be theory only and not used here) Any idea on the battery or power that would require? I was going to try a parabolic transmitter for the antenna gain.  Is it as easy as just connecting the controller to the parabolic transmitter?

Comment: Welcome.  Even just in theory ... getting ~10 mile radio reception requires non-trivial radio knowledge (power, signalling, antennas, regulations, safety etc).  But 3G/4G data services are more easily handled.  These kinds of questions are much better on a drone or RC site than an electronics one.